# Call a variadic function using a variable template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const Args&... args)
{
    //...
}

template<typename... Args>
auto fooChar = foo<char, Args...>;

template<typename... Args>
auto fooInt = foo<int, Args...>;
```

To be able to make use of these variable templates, I need to explicitely type the template parameters, like so:

```
fooChar<int, char, const char*>(5, 'a', "bar");
```

However, in a standard variadic function call, the template parameters are implicitely deduced based on the actual function parameters type. In other words, I would like to be able to use the variable templates like so, but the extra level of indirection seems to restrict this:

```
fooChar(5, 'a', "bar");
```

Obviously, I could simply define simple wrapper functions instead of variable templates, like so:

```
template<typename... Args>
void fooChar(const Args&... args)
{
    return foo<char>(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void fooInt(const Args&... args)
{
    return foo<int>(args...);
}
```

But overall, it just seems bulkier and less convenient. So, is there any way I could achieve the same result while using variable templates? If not, why is it impossible for the compiler to "forward" the parameters to the aliased function and thus deduce the variadic types?

Comment: `[](auto &&x)->decltype(auto){return foo<char>(x...);}`

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap `foo()` in a struct:

```
template <class T>
struct fooWrapper {
    template <class... Args>
    void operator()(Args const&... args) const {
        foo<T>(args...);
    }
};
```

Now make your variable templates be instantiations of this wrapper:

```
fooWrapper<char> fooChar;
fooWrapper<int> fooInt;
```

With the added bonus that you can pass `fooChar` to a function template, since it itself is not a function template.

Comment: Does it have any drawbacks since these are **globally** instantiated unlike variable templates which are only declared?

Comment: @JérémiP. I mean, you can make them variable templates if you want. `template <class T> fooWrapper<T> fooT;`

Answer (score -1):

A wrapper is needed:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const Args &&... args)
{
    //...
}

template<typename ...Args>
inline void fooChar(const Args && ...args)
{
    foo<char>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Hopefully, your compiler will optimize away the function call.

Comment: I believe that using `forward` and move semantics here is overkill - parameters of `foo` are const-references which could be safely bound to either rvalue or lvalue. Isn't simple `const Args& ...args` fine?

Comment: For `const` references, not using forward is fine. But, the odds are high that forwarding references would be the correct choice in the original code; it's probably just a lack of familiarity with them, here.

Comment: In my case, I'm never passing r-value references as parameters to these functions. So move semantics is in fact overkill. Anyway, I did not specified the calling context in my original question for the sake of simplicity. So it was impossible for you to know these informations.

Comment: Any explanation on why it is impossible for the compiler to "forward" the parameters to the aliased function and thus deduce the variadic types when using variable templates?

Comment: If you want to use `forward` and forwarding references, then don't use `const`.